# Fiddler AutoResponder rule to match only URL without prefix

Tags: regex, fiddler

How to create Fiddler AutoResponder rule that won't respond URLs with prefixes? For example:

MATCH THIS URL = https://abc.min.js
DON'T MATCH THIS URL = https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/loader14.html?https://abc.min.js

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was simple. I've downloaded loader14.html and add the first rule EXACT:https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/loader14.html?https://abc.min.js "respond with" loader14.html, after it goes the second rule https://abc.min.js which responds with my js file.